# Add Motor Speed controller to floor heating mat?

Tags: dimmer, leakage

EDIT: I've updated the question.  Would it be safe to add an inline PWM motor speed controller as a dimmable controller?  I'm having trouble finding a floor heating mat in my country domestically.  I'm thinking about removing the 9-position switch and rewiring directly to the heating mat, as suggested below, and adding a 500W PWM AC motor speed control module dimmer, that works on 110-220V.  Assuming the mat without the controller is safe, would that be a safe design?

---original question---
I have a floor heating mat I got on aliexpress that causes problems when it's on.  (This one, with the 9-position switch. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005876839978.html)  It only has a two-prong plug, unfortunately.  When I turn it on, I can feel electrovibration/surface currents on the metal devices on my desk when I run my fingers along them (bottom of monitor, USB connected boxes made of metal, etc.).  Nothing that shocks me but it's worrisome.  Worse than that, my USB DAC immediately (w/in 10 seconds) disconnects from my computer whenever the heating pad is on.  Turn off the heating pad, and the DAC is instantly (<1 sec) recognized by the computer again.  Every time.

I took a non-contact voltage tester (the orange Ames kind) and brought it near devices on my desk.  With the heating pad off, the voltage tester doesn't beep.  As soon as I turn on the heating pad, the voltage tester beeps when it gets near anything on my desk--screen, USB hub, DAC, USB cable plugged into USB hub, everything.  I think that means it's detecting AC voltage in everything. It says it only triggers above 60 VAC.  Which explains why the DAC bugs out and why I feel surface currents.

Note I use three-prong grounded outlets and surge protectors/power strips for everything that has a 3-prong plug.  I don't know how great the grounding is in my outlets, but I took my multimeter and tested 238V between hot and neutral and 238V between hot and ground (and a very small voltage between neutral and ground).

Any advice?  I'm guessing the 9-position switch uses a simple triac like a light dimmer.  Could that be messing up the waveform to the rest of the devices on the circuit, and isn't really anything to worry about?  Is there any way to ground a two-prong heating pad?  Or something else I can do to isolate it?  Or is this dangerous and should I chuck it/return it as defective/get my money back?  Thanks!

Edit: Just tried using multimeter in Hz mode near devices on my desk.  It measures .05 kHz (=50Hz) when the heating mat is on, with the probes in the air anywhere near my screen or devices on my desk, or with the probes touching them.  Turn off the heating mat and the multimeter immediately drops to 0 kHz.  AC power here is 240V/50Hz.

Comment: Sounds like you have huge common-mode/induced currents running all over due to PWM or triac control of the heating mat.  "I have a floor heating mat I got on aliexpress" Maybe get another mat from a reputable supplier that has passed EMC testing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'd love a good link explaining common-mode/induced currents.  I googled but found mostly RF/EMF discussions, which I'm not sure are relevant.  In any event, I'm trying to find something domestically but am striking out on finding anything in my country.

Answer (score 1):

> Any advice?

Throw that piece of trash out and buy from a legit brand domestically. It will cost much more, yes, but you get exactly what you pay for.

I don't think you're set up to re-engineer a faulty product like that, so homebrew fixes should not be considered - you need to know enough to be able to engineer the whole thing from scratch, except you got lousy parts to work around for some of it.

Comment: Note that heating pads are especially the kind of electrical appliance that causes house fires. So, unless this actually comes with the *truthful* certification it needs (and that seems impossible considering the interference), this thing will exclude you from insurance coverage if you're insured against fire. Much worse, it might kill you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I agree I'm not set up to re-engineer something like this, unless it's really simple.  I'm looking for something reputable domestically with certification, but unfortunately I'm striking out finding anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea that the dimming control of that mat is the source of all the issues is very likely.

Obviously it contains badly engineered electronics.

Unless you are an advanced electronics guy, there is not much you can do about it.

The simplest approach might be to throw away the dimming control and wire the mat directly to the mains plug (thus it is always at 100% power without any fancy electronics). This should remove noise and ground loops a lot. Still one needs to care for overheating. Surely also insulation should be critically inspected.

I would not trust this device. According to your description it is a possible threat to your electronics. It could also be a threat to your health, should you ever meet an insulation desaster. And last, but not least, it can light up your household.

Why not buy something domestically with the least safety certification?
Look if you can get hold of a heating mad with a 3-prong plug, and consider using a RCD in front of it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm considering removing the dimming control and wiring the mat directly to the mains, as you've suggested.  I think it would get too hot then, however, as this mat says it goes up to 500W.  Would it be a safe design to add a PWM AC motor speed control/dimmer to it that works up to 500W on 240V?  
(Something along the lines of this, though I would make sure it has certification: https://www.amazon.com/Sipytoph-Control-Regulator-Constant-Adjustable/dp/B095J3FYKH/ref=sr_1_5)